# Proving that if coNP $\neq$ NP then P $\neq$ NP

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, np, p-vs-np

I am new in complexity theory and this question is a part of a homework that I have and I am stuck on it.

> Let ${\sf coNP}$ be the class of languages $\{\overline{L}: L \in {\sf NP} \}$.
>
> Show that if ${\sf NP} \neq {\sf coNP}$, then ${\sf P}\neq  {\sf NP}$.

Comment: What have you tried? We know that $P\subseteq NP$.  Also, $P$ is closed under complementation. Can you see how to use these in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 20):

It is maybe easier to consider the contrapositive, that is ${\sf P}={\sf NP} \Rightarrow {\sf NP}={\sf coNP}$.

So assume ${\sf P}={\sf NP}$, then

1. for every $L\in {\sf NP}$, we have $L\in {\sf P}$, and since the languages in ${\sf P}$ are closed under complement,  $\bar L\in {\sf P}$ and therefore $L\in {\sf coNP}$.
2. for every $L\in {\sf coNP}$, we have $\bar L\in {\sf P}$, and since the languages in ${\sf P}$ are closed under complement,  $ L\in {\sf P}$ and therefore $ L\in {\sf NP}$.

**Remark:** Note that if ${\sf P}={\sf NP}$ the polynomial time hierarchy collapses to the lowest level, which implies that ${\sf P}={\sf NP}={\sf coNP}={\sf PH}$.

Comment: the proof that $\Sigma_i^P = \Sigma_{i+1}^P$ implies the PH collapses to the $i$-th level is a very slightly beefed up version of what you wrote.

Comment: _the simple proof/ relevant fact is that P is closed under complement!_